# How to access a symfony session without declaring any variables? (Symfony components interacting with Legacy code use case)

Tags: php, symfony, session

Say I have a single line, not in a class anywhere, and I know the session has a variable called "foo" that I want to output.

In standard PHP, I could simply...

```
echo $_SESSION["foo"];
```

So what do I need to do in order to the equivalent using a symfony session? 
I'm not in a function, not in a class, not passing any variables from point A to point B, no $request variable, no $session. I simply want to output "foo" from the session. How do I go about doing this?

This is in a legacy codebase that has a fair chunk of procedurally written code.

Comment: If you are not in a function, or class, where are you?

Comment: Like [that](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I'm in some legacy code area that's written procedurally. Not in anything, but somehow symfony sessions are still active.

Comment: @msg That looks like it gets a new session, not an existing one?

Comment: Is a new `Session` object, not necessarily a new session, but it could be. By default it'll use the `NativeSessionStorage` class, and that calls `session_start`. You'd need to know the session configuration to reattach correctly. Chances are that is using the defaults. Some [light reading](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Session.php#L39).

Comment: A more [relevant link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html) for your use case.

Comment: @msg That's getting me a lot closer, thankyou.

Comment: Is it any particular framework or just Symfony or Symfony components? You might want to add that info so experienced users can chime in. I think the safe, *for-sure* approach will be bootstraping the framework so it loads its configuration. Have a look at the sf app front controller, if possible.

Comment: @msg Just components I think. Redoing any framework setup is largely out the window at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: since you are using PHP, you still *could* use the `$_SESSION` super global to access session variables.

Option 2: otherwise you can use Symfony's Session class, documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Option 3: create a helper that abstracts Symfony's session. In your `composer.json` file add a `files` [definition](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) in your `autoload` section:

```
{
   "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/helpers/SessionsHelper.php"]
   } 
}
```

P.S. don't forget to `composer dump-autoload`.

Now, inside of `SessionsHelper` you can create functions that are globally accessible:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

/**
 * Retrieve a value from Session
 * 
 * @param $key [String]
 * @return [String]
 */
function getSessionValue($key)
   $session = new Session();
   return $session->get($key);
}
```

Now you can use `getSessionValue` anywhere in code:

```
echo getSessionValue('user_id');
```

Comment: Very good answer to the question as originally worded. Doesn't help my particular use case quite exactly (see my comments with @msg for why), but very useful suggestions.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, then you should be able to access your variable the way you originally posted - `$_SESSION['foo']`. Are you positive that's being stored in session in the first place? Do you see the entry you expect when you `die(var_dump($_SESSION))`?

Comment: I'm not setting the variables, the're set somewhere else in the code during the session.